# Failure to debug Direct3D application with video decoding acceleration

Tags: c++, direct3d9

I'm developing a video player with DXVA2.
While trying to debug Direct3D, I've switched it to the Debug mode from the control panel and have defined `D3D_DEBUG_INFO` macro.

Then, immediately, I've got `GetDecoderDeviceGuids` failed with the return code 0x80004005.

When I undefine `D3D_DEBUG_INFO`, `GetDecoderDeviceGuids()` succeeds.

I use windows 7 32bit, Direct3D 9, ATI Radeon HD 4550 with the latest drivers.

Is it possible to override this error somehow and use enhanced Direct3D debugging?

UPDATE: Forgot to mention, my player doesn't use neither DirectShow, nor Media Foundation. It uses FFmpeg library to decode video, code was copied from the VLC.

Comment: Direct3D 9 Debugging in the legacy DirectX SDK (June 2010) works on Windows 7. Note that Direct3D 9 debugging is not available on Windows 8.x.